# Mimic the structure of a javascript array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've been interested in using the splice function on my HTMLCollection Object.

```html
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>Collections</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="list">
      <div style="background-color:lightblue">item1</div>
      <div>item2</div>
      <div style="background-color:lightblue">item3</div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="BtnColourItem2_Click()">Colour Item2</button>
```

Lets assume the list was generated by a server side language like ASP.Net

```
function BtnRemoveItem2_Click()
{
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list[1].style.backgroundColor = "LightBlue"
    //list.splice(1,1)//goal colour the second item and recolour the others to white 
    for(var item in list)
        list[item].style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Now if this was an array the splice method would exist and I could use it.

*note: I've accomplished the functionality by pushing the seperate divs into an actual array to splice the one not needed.*

I have tried this:

```
list.trunc = [].splice;
list.trunc(1, 1);
for(item in list)
    console.log(item.innerText);
//results were
//item1
//item2
//item3
```

Gave me no errors but didnt work.
So I threw this together:

```
newList = new Object();
newList.trunc = [].splice;
newList.push = [].push;
newList.push(list[0].innerText);
newList.push(list[1].innerText);
newList.push(list[2].innerText);
newList.splice(1,1);
console.log(newList);
//outputs { 0 : "item1" , 1 : "item3"}
```

I found that quite cool.
So here is my question.
How do you structure an object Array-like enough to get the splice function to work without need to use the push or methods used to enter Array items?

Comment: you could set your object to extend array. `var myArrayLike = Object.create(Array.prototype);` This will give `myArrayLike` all the methods of `Array`

Comment: @atmd sounds like that would work. Ill give it shot. still looking for the data structure of the array though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
Thanks @Paul S 
It seems Jscript will allow the call of the splice function on an object. I tried that before like this:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj[0] = "item1";
obj[1] = "item2";
obj[2] = "item3";
obj.trunc = [].splice;
obj.trunc(1,1);
console.log(obj);
//outputs
//Object {0: "item1", 1: "item2", 2: "item3", trunc: function}
```

but I did not add the length property, so adding to the code above:

```
var countNum = 0;
for (var item in obj)
    !isNaN(parseFloat(item)? countNum++ : "";
obj.length = countNum;//number of num-indexed properties 
obj.trunc(1,1);
console.log(obj);
//outputs
//Object {0: "item1", 1: "item3", trunc: function}
```

so as long as the structure is number-index and has a length property the splice function will work on it.

Therefore the data structure of an array in javascript is reliant on the properties :

- number index
- length

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, the easiest thing to do with an array-like object when you want actual array functionality is to call `slice()` on it to create an array:

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLikeObject);
```

Once you do that, you'll have an actual array and can do whatever you want with it.

You cannot add or remove elements on an actual `HTMLCollection`. It doesn't allow modification like that, and that's why calling `splice()` on it doesn't work. But if you create an array from it as shown above, you can modify the array as needed.

As Paul S. notes below in the comments, an HTMLCollection is "live" and is dynamically updated to reflect the current state of the DOM. That's why you can't manually change it. If you place it into an array, the array will not dynamically update to accommodate DOM changes, but most of the time I think one would want an array to stay still and not change underneath one's nose.

Comment: Might be worth also mentioning that a _HTMLCollection_ or _NodeList_ can be **live**, but the _Array_ created by slicing it will not be live

Comment: I like it. quicker than the way I used to turn it into an array. is there no structure that splice will work on without using back end functions to turn it into an array though?

Comment: @Sarfaraaz What do you mean by "is there no structure that splice will work on"? I don't understand what you're getting at. You can't use splice on an HTMLCollection because it is read-only.

Comment: @Sarfaraaz `splice` will work on _Array-like Objects_  as long as you can change it's indexed properties; i.e. `var obj = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', length: 3}; Array.prototype.splice.call(obj, 1, 1); obj;` works. However, this is not true for a _HTMLCollection_ or _NodeList_, `document.body.childNodes[0] = 0; document.body.childNodes[0] === 0; // false`

Comment: @JLRishe I understand the HTMLCollection wont work because the resources are tied into browser and its memory. What I am looking for is a way to add the built in array function to an object similar to Paul S.'s method except I want the object to contain a reference within itself so if you cycle through the object with "for ... in" the method reference shows up. I am liking these work arounds though thanks Paul S and JLRishe