# Json Object push not working using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a data with certain rule. I want to create a json object to manage the rule. There is problem to create a json object as my need. Here my array data.

```
 $scope.data = ["Crust^Pan^Medium=NA", "Crust^Pan^Large=NA", "Crust^Thin Crust^Medium=10.50"]
```

I want a output like this:

```
  {
     "Pan": {
             "Medium": NaN,
             "Large": NaN,
          },
    "Thin Crust": {
             "Medium": 10.50
          }
   }
```

Here my code,

```
   $scope.crustRule = {};


    for(var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++) {
        var tempCrust = {};                        
        var trimOne = $scope.data[i].split('^');
        var trimTwo = trimOne[2].split('=');
        if(trimOne[0] == 'Crust') {
           tempCrust[trimTwo[0]]=parseFloat(trimTwo[1]);
           $scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]].push(tempCrust);
        }
    }
    console.log($scope.crustRule);
```

Comment: are you getting an error? if not what are you getting? and what does the question have to do with angular?

Comment: i get a error in my console of  `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: heh! which makes the answer pretty obvious...

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create an object `$scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]]` before you can push objects into it. Something like

```
$scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]] = {};
$scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]].push(tempCrust);
```

Comment: the push method should only exist in array like objects. but $scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]] is an empty object. [this question might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701114/mimic-the-structure-of-a-javascript-array-object/29742721#29742721)

Comment: again error print in console `$scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]].push is not a function`

Comment: as @Sarfaraaz, push should be use with arrays; not so much with objects. you can define `$scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]]` as arrays, or just use assignment instead of push:  `$scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]][trimTwo[0]]=parseFloat(trimTwo[1])`

Comment: not getting proper answer. Loop ever execute, to declare new array to clear old values.

Comment: @Aniruth I think you need to set the templated variable outside of the loop

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. In any event, your first problem was that `$scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]]` was not initialized. So you got "undefined" error. The second (somewhat unrelated) problem is that you are trying to use push function on an object, not on array. Step back and solve the problem without push (I showed you one of the ways). UPD: "the last comment" that I don't understand is @Aniruth - not @Sarfaraaz

Answer (score 1):

the push function has to exist. you can grab it from the Array property if you want.
only do this if it has to be in an object structure

```
var x = {length:0,push:Array.prototype.push};
x.push("jump");
console.log(x);//Object {0: "jump", length: 1}
```

[I go over the mininmum requirement for some array functions to work on an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701114/mimic-the-structure-of-a-javascript-array-object/29742721#29742721):

[Mimic the structure of a javascript array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701114/mimic-the-structure-of-a-javascript-array-object/29742721#29742721)

**EDIT:**
I noticed your reuirements are need an object without a length and string index based instead of number index based. going to test something

darn I was hoping something wild was already there and tried

```
var x = {};
x += {"BadGuy": "Joker"};
console.log(x)//[object Object][object Object] //:(
```

so I made my own push function

```
var x = {push:ObjPush};
x.push("jump");//Object cannot add (string) yet Coming soon
y = {"BadGuy": "Joker"};
x.push(y);
console.log(x);//{"BadGuy": "Joker"};

function ObjPush(obj)
{
    if ((typeof obj).toLowerCase() == "object")
    {
        for (var i in obj)
        {
            this[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Object cannot add (" + typeof obj + ") yet\n Coming soon");
    }
}
```

> **Note:**
>   I haven't added any handling to check for same properties. so any properties with the same name **will** override original properties.

**EDIT:**
I integrated my code with yours and got a strange output unfortunately.
for some reason instead of adding medium and large as properties to the inner objects it only adds the last 1 for example i get the output

```
{"Pan":{"Large":null},"Thin Crust":{"Medium":10.5}}
```

**EDIT:**
OK I found where my issue was. I get the expected output now. added a check to make sure that $scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]] is only initialized if it doesnt exist yet.

```
if(typeof $scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]] == "undefined")
    $scope.crustRule[trimOne[1]] = {push:ObjPush};
```